# Changing the MySQL password for MAMP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to change the current password for the root user for MAMP but I keep getting "Access denied!"

> phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

I completely installed MAMP from scratch and with the default root username and password everything worked fine.

I then changed the password using terminal and the following command

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqladmin -u root -p password newpassword
```

I also flushed privileges and then restarted the MAMP server.

With the new password I can successfully log into SQL from the terminal, but I can't get phpMyAdmin to work unless I change the password back to 'root'.

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://www.tech-otaku.com/local-server/changing-mysql-root-user-password-mamp/

Comment: -p password  means your password start with the character space. Try to put the password like this  -ppassword

Comment: Does phpMyAdmin prompt you for the username and password when connecting? I believe MAMP uses the auth_type config, which hardcodes the username and password in to a configuration file (usually `config.inc.php`, although I don't know if MAMP changes this). You'll have to edit the configuration file to reflect the new password.